# How can an AWS Lambda function update all records in a DynamoDB table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm working on an AWS Lambda function (Node 4.3) that needs to run through all the items in a DynamoDB table and update certain attributes.

The problem I'm having is how to get Lambda to wait until all of the DynamoDB operations are finished.

```
var async = require('async');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var doc = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    doc.scan({
        TableName: 'Occupations_dev'
    }, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data.Items.length);

        var funcs = [];

        data.Items.forEach(function (item) {
            funcs.push(function (cb) {
                item.Popularity = 0;

                doc.put({
                    TableName: 'Occupations_dev',
                    Item: item
                }, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("ERROR: " + item.Name);
                        cb(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Finished put for ' + item.Id)
                        cb(null, item);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        async.parallel(funcs, function (err, results) {
            console.log('Finished');

            if (err) {
                context.fail(err);
            } else {
                callback(null, 'Finished');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I tried using `async.parallel` to wait for all of the `db.put` requests to finish but it ends with a `Process exited before completing request` error whenever the Lambda function runs.

It does update *some* of the DynamoDB items but definitely not all of them.

I added some `console.log` calls when there are errors but the only output I see in the log is this:

```
START RequestId: b72fd7c6-14ed-11e7-a95a-c1185af4e870 Version: $LATEST
2017-03-30T02:08:11.691Z    b72fd7c6-14ed-11e7-a95a-c1185af4e870    1362
END RequestId: b72fd7c6-14ed-11e7-a95a-c1185af4e870
REPORT RequestId: b72fd7c6-14ed-11e7-a95a-c1185af4e870  Duration: 37165.80 ms   Billed Duration: 37200 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB 
RequestId: b72fd7c6-14ed-11e7-a95a-c1185af4e870 Process exited before completing request
```

What's the proper way to make the Lambda function wait until everything is done? (It's not a huge amount of data so I'm not worried about running longer than 5 minutes and timing out.)

Comment: I would imagine `Process exited before completing request` means there's some other error in your js code - does this work locally, and only error on AWS Lambda?

Comment: I'm relatively to new to Lambda so I don't actually know how to run it locally. Is there some way to get more error details from Lambda? I don't see anything in the CloudWatch logs.

Comment: Strange, they should be in Cloudwatch I believe. When you run the code snippet, are you seeing any of the `console.log` statements? Those should come through the log output in Lambda

Comment: I added some `console.log` statements for when the `doc.put` has an error but I don't see any of those any the log. I only see the output of `console.log(data.Items.length);` and about 60 of the `Finished put for...` statements before it dies.

Comment: Wild! Does DynamoDB have any constraints on simultaneous connections? If you are trying to insert too many records asynchronously, it could barf. Maybe try using a synchronous approach like `async.series` or `Promise.all` and see if your result is the same.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. I'll give `async.auto` (or maybe `waterfall`) a try and see what happens. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! I edited my last comment, I think `async.series` is what you'd want to try out. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: @BobbyMatson `async.series` did the trick! Looks like you were right about me flooding DynamoDB with too many connections. You should post that as an "answer" so I can accept it and give you proper credit. Thanks again. I spent literally _all day_ trying to figure this out.

Comment: will do! Glad it worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async.parallel` function invocations are occurring asynchronously, which is likely flooding DynamoDB with many simultaneous updates and raising "too many connections" errors at the DB level

I'd recommend using a synchronous operation, like `async.series` to perform the DB updates. DynamoDB should have not trouble processing these updates one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

The message "Process exited before completing request" means that the Javascript function exited before calling context.done (or context.succeed, etc.).

Here are some suggestions:

First of all, try increasing memory limit for the function. This line `Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB`  may indicate that memory is not enough and the process just gets killed without calling last callback.

What you will probably see after increasing memory limit is one of the following:

- Your function will timeout. In this case you may need to increase table's provisioned capacity (and/or your lambda timeout)
- Even if the function ends without timeout, you will probably see that not all the table records are processed. This is because scan and query operations may return not all the table's rows, if the total number of scanned items exceeds the maximum data set size limit of 1 MB. When a scan completes, you should check if LastEvaluatedKey is returned along with the data. If it is, you should make another scan providing LastEvaluatedKey value as ExclusiveStartKey parameter